# angular two different build command to generate different js file hashes

Tags: angular, caching, angular-cli, angular-universal

I have latest angular project. I got two different npm commands in `package.json`. Both of these commands executes `ng build --output-path=...` and generate build files in different locations using different `--output-path` flags.
Is there any flag or any property that I can apply in `angular.json` so that build files have different hashes for these two different npm commands? Something like hash prefix. So that `index.html` files are not identical since they import different js files.

The reason behind that is that: js files are cached. These two npm command is two different deployment (one for ssr one for csr) and I need to cache js files without cache overleaping for these two deployments (need different names).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `--output-hashing` param on the build command itself, e.g.:

```
ng build --output-path=... --output-hashing=bundles
```

The values are either `all`, `bundles`, `media` or `none`.

This will generate angular bundles with a hash like this: `main.62beb1fb93041eb44194.js`, and the index.html will link to those hashed versions.

Docs: https://angular.io/cli/build#options

You can also add the parameter into `angular.json` like this:

```
"build": {
      ...
      "options": {
        ...
        "outputHashing": "all",
      }
```